# redirect_to is not working when testing my action using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm testing an action but I can't make it pass.

My spec:

```
it 'redirects to the datatables page for authenticated users' do
    user = User.create(name: 'fer', email: 'fer@fer.fer', password: 'fer')
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    get :new
    expect(response).to redirect_to datatables_lists_path
  end
```

My code:

```
 def create
    user = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password] )
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to datatables_lists_path, notice: 'you are in!! :)'

    else
      flash[:error] = 'it's not working'
      redirect_to sign_in_path
    end
  end
```

The message I'm getting is:

```
  1) SessionsController redirects to the datatables page for authenticated users
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to datatables_lists_path
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
```

Comment: Try saving the user, user.save after your create it

Comment: hej there! When you create an item you usualy hit the DB, don't need to add save-method here. if you are talking about the spec

Comment: You're getting `:new` in the spec; seems like it should be `:create`.

Comment: Also, this looks problematic ;-) `flash[:error] = 'it's not working'`

Comment: I changed it u are right!:    it' puts  the signed in user in the session' do
      user = User.create(name: 'fer', email: 'fer@fer.fer', password: 'fer')
      post :create, email: user.email, password: user.password_digest, name: user.name
      expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(user.id)

    end

Comment: but now Im still getting an error:   Failure/Error: expect(session[:user_id]).to eq(user.id)

       expected: 1
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)

Comment: You shouldn't be setting `password` to `password_digest` in your `post :create` - that's not what the real user of your site would be submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're issuing a `get :new` and yet you're showing us the `create` action from your controller. Your test isn't testing the create action.